# Помогите написать код на Cи (Цикл While)

Tags: c

Задано действительны величины x, a, е (x != 0, a != 0, е > 0). Разработать программу, которая вычисляет значение суммы с заданной точностью е и указывает количество учтенных слагаемых.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эх, жаль, что придется закрывать вопрос - раз вы не потрудились хоть что-то сделать...

Answer (score 2):

Впрочем, небольшую подсказку я напишу :)

```
while(true)
{
    double x, a;
    scanf("%lf %lf",&x, &a);
    printf("Sum = %lf\n", exp(cos(a+x)/a));
}
```